# Running Excel Javascript API without opening Excel?

Tags: excel, office-js

Is it possible to run code from the Excel Javascript API without opening Excel? I'm not looking to use this in a server context, I'd just like to be able to run a Javascript script that interacts with the document from the command line.

Thanks for any input, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at leveraging the Office Open XML file format. There is, for example, an Open XML SDK for JavaScript that can be used to manipulate Office files directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this cannot be done. The Office JavaScript Library cannot initialize without getting information from a containing Office app, in which the JavaScript engine is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check into [Working with Excel in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0) which has a JavaScript SDK. See [Microsoft Graph SDKs overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) for more info.